# access particular set of pixels MTLTexture in metal

Tags: swift, metal, metalkit, mtlbuffer

I created an `MTLTexture` using `UIImage` data as follows.

```
var texture = metalView.currentDrawable!.texture
let uiImg = createImageFromCurrentDrawable()
            
guard let device = metalView.device else {
    fatalError("Device not created. Run on a physical device")
}
let textureLoader = MTKTextureLoader(device: device)
let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(uiImg)! as NSData
texture = try! textureLoader.newTexture(data: imageData as Data, options: [MTKTextureLoader.Option.allocateMipmaps: (false as NSNumber)])
```

what I need to do is change pixels color in `MTLTexture`. Not all of them. So, is it possible to access a particular set of pixels in `MTLtexture` and write into it in Metal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as a look at the [`MTLTexture` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtltexture) would have shown you. You can use one of the `getBytes()` methods to copy a region of texture data out to a buffer, and one of the `replace()` methods to replace a region of the texture's pixel with data from a buffer you supply.

Comment: got it.It worked.thanks for the tip Ken.Btw when I replace portion of pixels  in the texture, color values are changed from actual values of that particular set of pixels.Do you know any possible reason for this kind of behavior

Comment: Not sure. Depends on what you're doing exactly and the pixel format of the data you're supplying. Probably best to open a new question with those details, what you expected, and what you actually got.

Comment: Thanks ken.I figured it out lately.Yes indeed it's because of pixel format. Instead of pixelFormat: .bgra8Unorm in MTLTextureDescriptor i have  accidently  added .argb8Unorm which causes to unexpected behaviour.